# Template literal interpolation breaks whitespace table

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

When using template literals I noticed a problem with table formats.

When doing something like this:

```
var hello = 'Hello',
    bye = 'Goodbye';
console.log(`
    ${hello}    World
    ${bye}      World
`);
```

Because the {bye} part is four letters short of 'Goodbye' the string prints as:

```
    Hello    World
    Goodbye      World
```

This is made even more complex for interpolations of arrays, or objects.

I'm wondering if anyone has figured out a way to deal with this sort of problem. Where the spaced table formatting for a string can be kept during interpolation.

---

Suppose now a template tag uses strings, and arrays. The arrays are concatenated with spaces between words.

```
var hello = 'Hello',
    bye = 'Goodbye',
    phrase = ['I', 'like'];

console.log(someTag`
    ${hello}         World
    ${bye}           World
    Some things I like:
    ${phrase}        sunsets.
    ${['I', 'like']} candy.
`);
```

Just in case you can't tell the array square brackets, quotes, dollar, curly brace, and so on count towards the length of the string (visually) before interpolation. Spaces between words count towards string length after interpolation. The indents are effected by the loss of the extra characters, and addition of characters during the tag processing.

This question has an accepted answer, but I'd like to see more discussion. There can be more than one answer to this problem.

Comment: How will you solve this without template strings?

Comment: Very funny. There are table formatters, and padders for this kind of thing, but I did not expect the same problem with template strings which are known for being kind to white space. Further what if the insertions are required by some other tag function, and a table formatter/padder just produces a string. Yes the problem has been solved elsewhere, but it's entirely new type of problem for these template literals. I suppose the other option is just not to use them for this kind of thing.

Comment: Template literals do nothing to whitespace by default, they behave essentially like strings with interpolation. If you want more advanced behavior, you'd need to used a tagged template literal to do the conversion you're looking for.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I know. The length of the string is lost in the ${} characters, and various other operations inside a template tag. Sometimes it gets longer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tabs to compensate for the varying length of the words:

```js
const hello = 'Hello';
const bye = 'Goodbye';
const str = `
    ${hello}\t World
    ${bye}\t World
`;

console.log(str);
document.getElementById('demo').innerText = str;
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Comment: That is an easy solution. Thank you. What if the indent is unknown (spaces instead) as passed to a library? Sometimes a tab is visually 4 spaces, and sometimes 8 maybe 2. That might interfere as well if a replace of spaces with tabs is attempted. I suppose an error can be thrown if there are no tab characters, but I hope for a solution to the unknown white space problem.

Comment: You can combine one tab and multiple spaces. The tab will span the gap between the varying lengths of the string, and the spaces the requested padding. It won't be perfect, but it will be close to what you need.

Comment: There are multiple little tweaks that work as long as you know the string will always be the same (help output usually is). Makes me wish there was something like html, but for command line output.